# How to enable / disable accounts for Filevault2 pre-boot authentication?

Tags: mojave, filevault, login

I just upgraded to macOS 10.14.3 from High Sierra. My Mac has multiple user accounts and so far (i.e. macOS 10.12) I could always manage which users were allowed to unlock the encrypted Filevault2 volume pre-boot (image downloaded from [this website](https://www.macobserver.com/tips/quick-tip/macos-revoking-filevault-access/)):

[image]

However, in Mojave I cannot find the option to do so anymore.

[image]

(How) Can I enable and disable individual accounts for FV2 unlocking in Mojave?

---

**Update**: After disabling one user using the command line, the dialogue is now available in the System Preferences.

Answer (score 3):

I just remembered that there is a command line tool (`fdesetup`) to manage Filevault. Strange, Apple removed the option in System Preferences.

To remove the user "username":

```
sudo fdesetup remove -user username
```

To add the user "username":

```
sudo fdesetup add -usertoadd username
```

For more details:

```
man fdesetup
```